# Problema mensajes de validacion en login Default LARAVEL 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

estoy intentando hacer un modulo de login personalizado basado en el login por defecto(Route::auth()), pero de algún modo, aparecen los mensajes correspondientes a unas reglas de validacion 'required', en los dos campos, email y password, el problema es que no se donde se estan aplicando las reglas de validacion.
Este error me pasa también en el login por defecto.

FORMULARIO

```
@section('contenido')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    @if(count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role=alert > 
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <ul>
          @foreach($errors->all() as $errores)

              <li style="font-weight: bolder; list-style-type: none">{{$errores}}</li>
          @endforeach
           </ul>
         </div>       
        @endif


    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        @if(count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role=alert > 
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul>
              @foreach($errors->all() as $errores)

                  <li style="font-weight: bolder; list-style-type: none">{{$errores}}</li>
              @endforeach
               </ul>
             </div>       
            @endif


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="superespacio"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

         {{Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'method'=>'POST','class'=>"form-horizontal"))}}

                          <div class="form-group">
                               {!! Form::label('Correo Electronico', null, array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) !!} 
                               <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  {!! Form::text('correo', null, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' =>'Introduce tu Correo Electronico')) !!}

                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                           {!! Form::label('Contraseña', null, array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) !!} 
                           <div class="col-sm-10">
                              {!! Form::text('pass', null, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' =>'Introduce tu Contraseña')) !!}

                          </div>
                      </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                         {!! Form::submit('Inicia Session', ['class'=>'btn btn-default']) !!}

                    </div>
                </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}


    </div>
</div>
<div id="superespacio"></div>
@endsection
```

MODULO AUTHCONTROLLER(EL QUE VIENE POR DEFECTO)

<

```
?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
           //'name' => 'required|max:255',
          //  'correo' => 'required|unique:users',
          //  'pass' => 'required|min:6',
            //|email|max:255
            //|confirmed
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
           // 'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['correo'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['pass']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Como veis en este modulo tengo desactivadas todas las reglas de validacion, pues aun asi me intenta validar el correo y el password.

En el trait AuthenticatesUsers
He intentado comentar esta linea a ver si era por eso, mismo resultado

```
   protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            //$this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);
    }
```

La ruta

```
Route::auth();
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function() {
        Route::resource('usuarios', 'UsuariosController');
    });
```

La ruta funciona bien, al darle al link de usuarios te envia al middleware, pero como digo no paso del login al home, en la pantalla de validacion, aun rellenando los campos, me pone el mensaje de 'required'

/*****************************DESPUES DE EDICION********************
MODELO USER

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

     protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','tipo',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];



    public function articulos($value='')
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\modelos\articulo');
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que Laravel busca por defecto los campos `email` (o la propiedad `username` en la clase) y `password`, esto se puede ver en el trait [AuthenticatesUsers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php):

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    ...
    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);
    ...
}
```

Como lo puedes ver, la validación es la primera acción realizada por el método, a continuación el código correspondiente, aún en el mismo trait:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

El nombre de usuario se obtiene con un método también ubicado en el mismo trait:

```
public function loginUsername()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
}
```

---

Después de la introducción, **¿qué se puede hacer entonces?**

Hay muchas opciones, la más sencilla (tal vez no la mejor) puede ser sobreescribir el método `login` (o el método `validateLogin`, depende como lo quieras hacer), en tu controlador de autenticación:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'pass' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

Para esto necesitas también modificar un poco el método `loginUsername`, el cuál vamos a modificar a su forma más sencilla:

```
public function loginUsername()
{
    return 'correo';
}
```

Después de la validación hay que tener en cuenta la autenticación como tal, para lo cual necesita trabajar con el método `getCredentials` el cual se encuentra en el trait del cual ya hablamos:

```
// versión original
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');
}
```

En este método necesitaríamos cambiar la cadena `'password'` por `'pass'`.

Comment: Creo que el error viene de otro lado, ya que estoy intentando implementar tu solucion y siguen apareciendome los dos errores, es mas he intentado comentar las 3 lineas de los 3 metodos en el propio trait, y sigue saliendo el error, lo unico que se me ocurre que este cogiendo algun request de otra validacion pero también los tengo comentados, de hecho cuando intente implementar tu solucion en el controlador me dio este error

Comment: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::validateLogin() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTDOCS_PHP\Laravel_CodigoFacilito\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 59 and defined

He añadido esta clase al controlador y no me da este error, pero me salen los errores de siempre 

use Illuminate\Http\Request

Comment: Añadido modelo users al post principal por si acaso.

Comment: `use App\Http\Controller\Auth\Request;` en el controlador de autenticación.

Comment: Gracias, al final consegui solucionarlo, aunque tuve que usar el login por defecto.